# Basic way to find largest values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max

Let's say I have a dictionary. I want to find the 4 keys with the highest values. I want to do this in a very basic way. I'm not that advanced with CS. I just want to iterate over the dictionary. Or how should I do this? I realize it cannot be that challenging. I don't want to use heapq. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by highest values? Highest Number? Biggest length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555968/efficient-way-to-find-the-largest-key-in-a-dictionary-with-non-zero-value

Comment: Do you care what order the highest values are returned in?

Comment: @martineau I don't care in what order they are returned in

Comment: @martineau I just need it to be done in the most basic manner possible

Comment: @Zizouz212 Highest value, as in the keys with the largest integer values.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most pythonic way is:

```
sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)[:4]
```

Comment: `sorted(d, key=d.get)[-4:]` would be even shorter...

Comment: I voted this up as definitely better than mine, but I think I would make one amendment nonetheless. I dislike iterating over a `dict`'s keys by simply iterating over the `dict` -- I think that implicit behavior confuses folks all the time. I would prefer as more explicit `sorted(d.keys(), key=d.get ... )`

Comment: Using `d.get()` will be less optimal than the `O(n)` solution. Why not just iterate items? The solution used on `collection.Counter.most_common` is `sorted(self.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

Comment: @jwilner I kind of get what your saying. Can you show me what that amendment would look like?

Comment: @Beth, it's just slightly different from the above solutions. `max_keys = sorted(d.keys(), key=d.get)[:-4]` or alternatively, you could reverse if you like -- `sorted(d.keys(), key=d.get, reverse=True)[:4]`. My larger point is that people forget that `list(dict) == d.keys()`, and in those kinds of situations I think programmers should defer to the more explicit option.

Comment: @jwilner The problem with that is that it is wasteful on python 2.x, unnecessarily copying a list in memory which will be garbage collected later.  That the dicts iterate over the keys anyway should be common python knowledge, imo.

Comment: @JBernardo What O(n) solution do you speak about?  Aren't yours and mine both O(n log n) ?

Comment: @wim I mean the iteration. On worst case each `d.get(x)` can happen on O(n). Most of the time it will be a single hop in the hash table though

Comment: @JBernardo d.get is O(1).  It's only going to be O(n) if every hash is colliding - and you have to intentionally sabotage a dict to create that situation, it's not going to just happen by accident.

Comment: Are you sure you know about time complexity and dict implementation?  Because this depends heavily on the dictionary history of inserts and deletes. Also the "n"  in  O(n) for `d.get` is not the current number of elements but the size of the container which is at least 33% bigger to allow less hash collisions. Iterating directly is always more efficient  even with no collisions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `collections.Counter` object instead.

```
c = collections.Counter(original_dict)
c.most_common(4)
```

If you just want the keys, then:

```
[k for k, v in c.most_common(4)]
```

For reference on how it is implemented, check the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/774918b528c49baed5cb3c1b87bdffcfab561a6a/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L513-L524).

Comment: @Shashank you can use `Counter` to count anything. Try the code yourself. Also this is much cleaner

Comment: Taken back, it works :)

Comment: Good trick!  It uses heapq in the background

Answer (score 0):

Sort by the values and then slice. The `sorted` function takes a key function.

```
items_by_value = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v) 
keys = [k for k, v in items_by_value[-4:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Assuming `d` is the dictionary, and if you don't care what order the keys are in, you could use something like the following:

```
keys = [v[0] for v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[1])[-4:]]
```

For huge dictionaries, it would be a more efficient to use:

```
keys = [v[0] for v in sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[-4:]]
```

The `[-4:]` means the last four entries. In both cases, if you want the keys in the same order as their corresponding highest values, use `[-1:-5:-1]` instead, which are the last four entries in reverse order.